# Cancel functionality is not working while edit the content in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Hereby I have posted my code. I can edit the value and save. While editing the value in text area and click cancel button, the canceled text also saved and cancel is not working. Please give a solution for this scenario. Thank you

```css
// functions in the controller 
edit: function (value) {
  $scope.showEdit=true;
  $scope[value]=true;
  $scope.editText=angular.copy($scope.Contents);
}

,
cancel: function (value) {
  $scope[value]=false;
}

,
save: function () {
  var contentObj= {
    "text": $scope.editText.text
  }
  textService.edit(contentObj, this.onSuccessEdit, this.onFailureEdit);
}

,
onSuccessEdit: function (data) {
  $scope.showEdit=false;
  $scope.content.text=data;
}

,
onFailureEdit: function (data) {
  $scope.showEdit=true;
}
```

```html
<!-- Html code -->

<button ng-click="edit('edit')">edit</button>
<div ng-show="showEdit">
  <button ng-click="save('edit')">save</button>
  <button ng-click="cancel('edit')">cancel</button>
</div>

<p ng-if="!showEdit">{{content.text}}</p>
<div ng-if="showEdit" ng-model="content.text">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Call `edit`, `save`, `cancel` methods without `param` and use `$scope.showEdit` instead of `$scope[value]`

Comment: without using param the value cannot be edit

Comment: Edited the comment. Could you include the whole controller?  if you do so,  please format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `cancel` should be like this

```
cancel: function(value) {
    $scope.showEdit = false;
    $scope[value] = false;
    $scope.editText = null;
  },
```

A working Example here

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("text", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "test"
    $scope.showEdit = false;

    $scope.Contents = {
      text: "teeeeeeeeeest"
    };
    $scope.editText = '';
    $scope.modules = {
      edit: function(value) {
        $scope.showEdit = true;
        $scope[value] = true;
        $scope.editText = angular.copy($scope.Contents);
      },

      cancel: function(value) {
        $scope.showEdit = false;
        $scope[value] = false;
        $scope.editText = null;
      },

      save: function(value) {
        $scope.Contents = angular.copy($scope.editText);
        $scope.showEdit = false;
        $scope.editText = null;
        $scope[value] = false;
      },

      onSuccessEdit: function(data) {
        $scope.showEdit = false;
        $scope.content.text = data;
      },
      onFailureEdit: function(data) {
        $scope.showEdit = true;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="text">

    <button ng-click="modules.edit('edit')">edit</button>
    <div ng-show="showEdit">
      <button ng-click="modules.save('edit')">save</button>
      <button ng-click="modules.cancel('edit')">cancel</button>
    </div>

    <p ng-if="!showEdit">{{content.text}}</p>
    <textarea ng-if="showEdit" ng-model="editText.text">
      </textarea> Original Text: {{Contents.text}} <br> Editer Text: {{editText.text}}

  </div>
</div>
```